# NHibernate/ASP.Net state server exception (Unable to serialize the session state)

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, session, state

After upgrading to NHibernate 3.1 and .Net 4 I am seeing a strange exception in our web application. The error message may be familiar to many:

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

Switching to "inProc" mode, everything works fine. But we cannot use inProc mode in production.

**Now, the error only happens ONCE. Then goes away until the application is redeployed or restarted.**

Below is a complete stack trace as it appears in the log. Please note the following interesting points:

- PersistentGenericBag`1[DAL.DTO.Cargo] may indicate that this is related to lazy loading
- The serializer is trying to convert it to an Int32
- When investigating the session contents, I can find absolutely no DTO objects, or references to any. If I Clear() the session, the exception goes away, but our application breaks.

> [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[DAL.DTO.Cargo]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.]
>      System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value, IFormatProvider provider) +21
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary._*BinaryWriter.WriteValue(InternalPrimitiveTypeE code, Object value) +62
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.*_BinaryWriter.WriteMember(NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, Object value) +76
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteKnownValueClass(NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, Object data) +75
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteMembers(NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo memberTypeNameInfo, Object memberData, WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo) +198
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteMemberSetup(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, String memberName, Type memberType, Object memberData, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo) +139
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo, String[] memberNames, Type[] memberTypes, Object[] memberData, WriteObjectInfo[] memberObjectInfos) +186
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo) +480
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +444
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +133
>      System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1708
>   <
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.]
>      System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1793
>      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.WriteValueToStreamWithAssert(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +34
>      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Serialize(BinaryWriter writer) +638
>      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.Serialize(SessionStateStoreData item, Stream stream) +244
>      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.SerializeStoreData(SessionStateStoreData item, Int32 initialStreamSize, Byte[]& buf, Int32& length, Boolean compressionEnabled) +67
>      System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem) +114
>      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +807
>      System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be quite a nasty problem. There were indeed references to DTO objects stored in the session state, but they were hidden deeply enough so that simply inspecting the session contents manually did not reveal them.

In case anyone else runs into this problem after upgrading to NHib 3 and .Net 4; find a reproducible case and closely inspect your code or use code analysis tools. If there is no luck, try identifying all code that stores data in session, and simply use brute force until you find the offending data. Good luck!